# Spring Scurity - No puede ser encontrado el archivo \localhost:8080

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Este problema me sale cuando intendo iniciar mi proyecto usando estas dependecias.

```
<dependency>            
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>




<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>    
</dependency>
```

[image: Este es el cartel de error que me sale cuando lanzo la dependencias de spring security]

***TODO ESTA BIEN, FUNCIONA, HASTA QUE PONGO ESAS 2 DEPENDECIAS, TAL VEZ SEA POR LA VERSION??***